# Take profit and Stop loss are executing on bar close instead of amount set in strategy for backtesting

Tags: pine-script, back-testing

Im using a TP and SL script in one of my strategies for backtesting. The issue I'm having is the take profit or stop loss is triggering, but they are triggering on the close of the bar on which my percentage goal is reached instead of the actual percentage amount.

Example: I execute a buy order worth $1000 at 10:30 and set a SL of 1%. At 12:08 the stock price hits my SL of 1%. Using a 5min chart, the SL doesn't fill until 12:10 - the close of the 5min bar

In practice this wouldn't be an issue because the trade would in fact execute at the set TP/SL through my broker but when backtesting this causes large discrepancies in my strategy results.

here's my code as of now. Appreciate any insight

```
tp1 = input.float(title='Take Profit 1 - Target %', defval=100, minval=0.0, step=0.5, group='Take Profit', inline='Take Profit 1')
q1 = input.int(title='% Of Position', defval=100, minval=0, group='Take Profit', inline='Take Profit 1')

stoplossPercent = input.float(title='Stop Loss (%)', defval=999, minval=0.01,step=0.5, group='Stop Loss') * 0.01
slLongClose = close < strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stoplossPercent)
slShortClose = close > strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stoplossPercent)
```

Comment: and just to reassure anyone looking at this, "Recalculate on bar close" is not checked on my backtesting strategy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strategy.exit` in-built function to set stop loss and take profit of an open trade.

```
strategy.exit('Long_TP/SL', from_entry="Long Entry",  stop = long_SL,  limit = long_TP )
```

Comment: thank you. any idea where to place that inside this strat? https://www.tradingview.com/script/XIJrNXQc-Ultimate-Strategy-Template-Advanced-Edition/

Comment: I would recommend to code exit in ` if strategy.position_size > 0` for long condition, `<` for short